# Renamed an S3 bucket by accident in my SAM template and deployed it. Now stuck with UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE. How to recover this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I am working on a serverless app project using AWS SAM. Just serverless by principle but not using the actual `serverless` library, to be clear.

The template comprises S3 bucket definitions.
Recently, I deleted the last character of the name of one bucket by accident from the template, then deployed the changes in my development account. Saw that weird stuff happened in the console when `sam deploy` was running.

Let's say the correct name for the bucket is `mysuperapp-data`. By accident, it became `mysuperapp-dat`. CloudFormation tried to delete `mysuperapp-data`, which failed as not empty (fortunately!) and created `mysuperapp-dat`.

Having seen that, I type the missing character back, so that the bucket is named `mysuperapp-data` again, then deploy a second time.

The deployment fails because it tries to create the `mysuperapp-data` bucket that already exists, and terminates with one `UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE` thing.

Now, I am stuck. SAM aka CloudFormation does not want to update with the error:

```
Failed to create/update the stack: mysuperapp-dev, Waiter StackUpdateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Stacks[].StackStatus" we matched expected path: "UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" at least once
```

How can I recover from this state without deleting the entire stack? Is it possible to tell SAM / CloudFormation to just pick up the existing bucket and attach it to the stack?

The other solution would be to delete and recreate the stack, but I prefer to avoid it, because :

- The project has a Cognito user directory that I would need to repopulate manually after recreation (no export feature)
- New empty buckets would have to be created, and I got lots of data in the original ones, referenced by records in a RDS database. The database is not part of the template, but it would require hacking all the records to update the locators.